# Why can't I stream more than 1 file using nginx?

Tags: nginx

I've written a basic file server using Django. It runs on my Raspberry PI (1 CPU) and serves files from my NAS.

When I try to download files from it (multiple large files at once, ~500 Mb each), I can literally download only one or two at once. I don't know if the problem is nginx (which I've set up to serve static files), in my Django app (I'm running it using the development server instead of something like gunicorn), or just disk i/o.

My nginx config is:

```
user pi nogroup;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
accept_mutex off;
}

http {
include mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log combined;
sendfile on;
gzip off;

server {
    listen 80 default;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_pass   http://192.168.1.120:8000;
    }

    location /mnt/ {
    internal;
    alias /mnt/;
    }
}
}
```

How can I increase the throughput of my setup, or is the bottleneck just likely to be i/o?

Comment: We don't consider RPis to be topical within the meaning of our faq.

Comment: Useless comment. Want to actually point me to the faq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using the development server, you can only serve one request at a time. It has no threading/processing pool.